# What is a good method to implement a 'tab layout' in an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-tablayout

I am new to android development and wanted to implement a tab layout in an activity. I looked up a tutorial on YouTube (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNpWGI_hGGg). But after following the steps, it didn't work

code of activity class:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_directory.*

class DirectoryActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_directory)

        var viewpager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.container)
        setupViewPage(viewpager)

        findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabs).setupWithViewPager(viewpager)
    }

    fun setupViewPage(viewpager : ViewPager)
    {
        val adapter = object : SectionsPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager){}
        val frag_hst = object : FragDirecHst(){}
        val frag_sst = object : FragDirecSst(){}
        val frag_tor = object : FragDirecTor(){}

        adapter.addFragment(frag_hst, "HST")
        adapter.addFragment(frag_sst, "SST")
        adapter.addFragment(frag_tor, "TOR")

        viewpager.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

SectionsPagerAdapter class code:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm,FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    }


    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

After running, I got this error in the logcat:

***java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment null must be a public static class to be properly recreated from instance state.***

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: The logcat message should also have included a line number. Which line of your code is it complaining about, exactly?

Comment: `val frag_hst = object : FragDirecHst(){}` – The braces at the end are creating an anonymous subclass of `FragDirecHst`, which is not allowed, and is what the Exception message is saying. Remove the `{}` there, and on the next two lines.